# Putting text under a banner

Tags: html, css

So I'm designing a website, and I created a banner/header image with text in the centre of that banner, and I want all my main content to go under the banner (the banner is the type which covers the entire page, so that you scroll down to see the content. However, the main content does not automatically go down or up, depending on the size of the header, since I set the width to 100%, so it gets resized according to the size of the window, so could somebody help with this issue, so that it maintains the same ratio with the header/banner?
The HTML code:

```
 <div id="banner">
    <h1 id="head">head</h1>
    <img id="logo" src="Logo.jpg" alt="logo and banner"/>
</div>
<div id="everythingElse">
    <a href="#test">Scroll</a>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#head{
text-align: center;
position: absolute; 
top: 4%; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;
font-size: 100px
}

#logo{
width: 104%;
}

#banner{
position: absolute; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
min-width: 1200px;
}

#everythingElse{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute positioning. Use a height of `100vh` if [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) is acceptable, otherwise use `100%` and make sure your `body` and `html` elements are included in that rule.

Comment: So I should set the height of the banner or the main text content?

Comment: I'd expect that you'd want the outer wrapper to be the height of the viewport.